# Enable CORS in ASP .NET Core 2.1 Web Api

Tags: asp.net, cors, axios

I'm writting application in ASP .NET Core 2.1 Web API and React. I have my server on localhost:5000 and my client on localhost:3000. I wanted to send post request with axios but in browser console i see error:

```
OPTIONS https://localhost:5001/api/auth/login 0 ()
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
at createError (createError.js:16)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)
```

In my Web API I try to add CORS but it doesn't seems to work. I add:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();
    services.AddMvc();
    ...
}
```

And:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors(options =>
        options
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials());
    ...
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

And this is my post request:

```
const response = await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login',

        data: {
            userName: this.state.controls.login.value,
            password: this.state.controls.password.value
        }
    });
```

Server console after request:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 OPTIONS http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[4]
      Policy execution successful.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 4.253ms 204
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login application/json;charset=UTF-8 52
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[4]
      Policy execution successful.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 2.1805ms 307
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[32]
      Connection id "0HLG4CH3JIV16", Request id "0HLG4CH3JIV16:00000002": the application completed without reading the entire request body.
```

When I use Postman everything is fine. I receive json with token from server.

Comment: if you don't need CORs when deployed, then you can setup a proxy for your development environment only. what are you using as your dev webserver?

Comment: I use development server built in create-react-app. How can I setup proxy?

Comment: Ok, I set proxy in package.json and change my url in axios to "/api/auth/login" but in console I still se the same. I don't know why its redirecting me to https and port 5001 even if i set http and port 5000 in proxy

Comment: Even if i set proxy in axios config i still have the same problem, nothing change

Comment: this might be of some help. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/800. sorry, I don't mess with react much. I have gotten this to work in angular, but that is a different wrapper for express. good luck

Comment: @MuchaJusia Have you added `EnableCors` attribute on your AuthController class?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood Yes. But in console I can see that "Policy execution successful", so maybe is not a problem with cors? Why can my application completed without reading the entire request body?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I resolve my problem. I just didn't know that I should remove "app.UseHttpsRedirection();".

Comment: Thank you very much. Wasted all day searching for this solution

Comment: Why remove UseHttpsRedirection?