# .net core 2.1 CORS api

Tags: c#, ajax, .net-core

I've got an api that handles a post ajax request.  When I call it, I'm getting the infamous Cors error message:

> > Access to XMLHttpRequest at '' from origin '' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

No problem.  I've done this before and their is plenty of resources out there (e.g. [Enable CORS in ASP .NET Core 2.1 Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51900055/enable-cors-in-asp-net-core-2-1-web-api)) describing how to add a cors policy to the startup.  Problem is I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is my Sartup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";


    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
            builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("*").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyOrigin();
            });
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            // User settings
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;

            // Password settings
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
        })

            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true);

        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());

        });

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {

        app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
        }
        else
        {

            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        //UserDbContextSeed.Seed(serviceProvider).Wait();
    }//Configure

}
```

}

Here is my route attribute for my controller:

```
    [Route("api/v23")]
```

Here's my method signature

```
  [Route("[action]")]
    [HttpPost]       
    [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Post_Data(model v){......}
```

Finally here is my ajax requtest:

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Myserver/api/v23/Post_Data',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json", //
                data: JSON.stringify(Param),
                success: function (result) {
                     console.log(results);
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
```

I've tried adding the [Enable CORS("__myAllowSpecificOrigins") attribute to the controller, but that doesn't work either.  This shouldn't be hard, I'm obviously missing something obvious.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change syntax of AddCors to this:

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy(AllowSpecificOrigins, builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));
```

Comment: For those who are wondering what was changed, Sergey had me remove .WithOrigins("*").  Works like a charm.